# Ошибка при отправке JSON пакета с jQuery на Java Spring RestController

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, spring-boot

При отправки JSON пакета с отдельного HTML файла на Java Spring RestController при помощи jQuery, java выдает предупреждение :

> Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not
>   supported]

При этом все MediaType указаны.

Chrom выдает еще 2 ошибки:

> POST http://localhost/post 415

и

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/post' from origin 'null'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.

Код контроллера:

```
@RestController
public class mainController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Object> postUser(@RequestBody User user){
System.out.println(user);
return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Код jQery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#go').on('click', function() {

var user = {
    "name" : "Tom",
    "age" : 23
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/post',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: user
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});


  });
});
```

Огромная просьба подсказать где ошибка и как решить подобную проблему?

P.S. Т.К. опыта у меня маловато просьба сказать как пишутся подобные приложения, а именно сперва Backend и потом при помощи Thymeleaf или Mustache шаблонов Front, или же Frontend совсем пишется отдельно как у меня?

Comment: Писать фронт на тимлиф неразумно, надо делать корс запрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, разобрался. Надо было поднять HTTP сервер чтобы не было блокировки CORS и подправить MediaType, а именно оставил только `produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE}.`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost/post",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(user),
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true
});
```

Comment: Настроил Nginx чтобы не выходила блокировка CORS, вставил ваш код, остальные ошибки остались.

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу request со всеми header, который отправляет ваша форма. Чтобы понять почему у вас была блокировка CORS, надо видеть конфиг вашего приложения. Какие зависимости подключены и как и что настроено.

Comment: Была блокировка CORS потому что я не поднял HTTP сервер.